# game-engine : error totblock : 1. Memory Leak?

Tags: game-engine, memory-management

I've got this error when running the blender game-engine:
`Error Totblock: 1`

(The scene is running, but very slow, and this message appears a the end)

Apparently, it is due to a memory leak.

I've got a quite big scene probably : it's a game level with 8 rooms, and a total of 1408 verts, 1066 faces, 2132 Tris, and Mem of 1882.78M. 
(The size may be due to jpeg that I use in each room)

Is this message the way for Blender to tell me that this scene is too big for it... or has this scene some particular problems in memory management? If it is so, could anyone give me a clue how to search the memory leak?

EDIT:

I've made a test with another blend. This one has a size of 14M only and I still see the error message. Apparently, it's due to objects that I have linked to my current blend. Still don't know what the problem with the particular object linked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender uses a memory management system that keeps track of the number of memory allocations it has made. When blender finishes it reports the number of remaining memory allocations. A small number is of little concern but a large number indicates that memory is being allocated and not released, meaning a memory leak.

If you start blender from a terminal (or show the windows console) you will see a similar message as blender quits `Error: Not freed memory blocks: xx` while blenderplayer gives the more cryptic `Error Totblock: xx`

This is related to blenders source code and not likely from anything you have done in your game creation. If you do see large numbers it might be worth reporting or talking with a developer on irc to help find a cause.

Personally I think this should be disabled for normal user usage. Only blender developers would have any interest in this information.